# Can't select the current database name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I need to write a code that finds the name of the current sql database and puts that name in a variable. I'll take any suggestions, but what I was thinking was querying the current database name and putting that in a variable. I don't know if that will work because I can't seem to query my database name at all. The database I'm using for this is named "wp_plugin_development" but the query won't show me that. I'm using the code:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];
```

to get the database name in phpMyAdmin, but it brings up an error saying:

> ## 1305 - FUNCTION wp_plugin_development.DB_NAME does not exist

I don't know why it's doing that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: your code "SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];" seems like sql server however the question is tagged as mysql. which one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress database name is [already stored as a constant](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Name) in a standard **wp-config.php**. You can access it with `DB_NAME`.

```
<?php $database_name = DB_NAME; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL try:

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

or refer to this:

[MySQL Doc: How to get DB Info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> ```
> global $wpdb;
> echo $wpdb->dbname;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT schema();

can be used to retrieve the current db name in Mysql. this can also be assigned to a variable using AS keyword.